# linux: touch empty file and zip in one command

Tags: linux, unix, zip, touch

I need to create a bunch of .gz files for testing something. Is it possible (in unix based shell) to make an empty file (e.g. by `touch file1`) and zip (e.g. file1.gz) using a simple one-liner (along: `touch file1 | zip` ).  How can I redirect the file into zip?

Comment: `gzip < /dev/null > file.gz`?

Comment: Works ! - what's the /dev/null doing here ?

Comment: Just an easy way to feed ‘nothing’ into `gzip`'s STDIN. You could use `: | gzip`, `echo -n | gzip` or a number of different ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gzip < /dev/null > file.gz
```

I.e. feed `gzip` empty input and redirect the output to `file.gz`. No temporary empty file needed.

This assumes that there's a `/dev/null` available (i.e. a POSIX(-ish) system). Alternatives would be:

```
:         | gzip […]
true      | gzip […]
printf '' | gzip […]
echo -n   | gzip […] # Won't work in strictly POSIX environments
…
```

I.e. anything that's available and prints nothing to STDOUT.

---

<sup>You mentioned `zip`, but since you said you needed `.gz` files I assume you want `gzip`.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
touch file1 && zip file1.zip file1
```